# integrating yeoman with socketstream

Tags: node.js, sockets, gruntjs, yeoman, socketstream

I have been developing angular yeoman project and the development process is elegant with yeoman providing necesaary tools for development purposes. At this stage of the project, we are looking to add socketstream into this project but socketstream offers some similar usage as yeoman does but often with conflict. For example like how both provide a different directory structure, Is it possible to use socketstream and add some build/lint tasks to it? Or is there a way to integrate yeoman and SS for a project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project to make a Yeoman generator for SocketStream here: https://github.com/Anephenix/yo-socketstream. It is currently a work in progress.

In the future, we are looking to make SocketStream more flexible in how it works with 3rd-party client-side tools like Grunt, Bower and Yeoman.